# MySQL apply multiple conditions in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table named `users` that contains the following columns:

```
id
login
status
```

Now I want to create a page of statistics in PHP and I want to see how many users have status=0, how many users have status=1, how many users have status=2.

I want to do this the most efficient possible way, without having to run 3 queries.

Right now I only know to do this with 3 queries in UNION:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE status='0') UNION (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE status='1') UNION (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE status='2')
```

I dont know too much SQL programming but I was thinking that something like this might work:

```
SELECT IF(status='0',stat0++),IF(status='1',stat1++),IF(status='2',stat2++) FROM users GROUP BY status
```

But it doesnt work because the syntax is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

query returns count of statuses in 1 row

```
select
  sum(case when status = '0' then 1 else 0 end) as c1,
  sum(case when status = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as c2,
  sum(case when status = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as c3
from users 
where status = '0' or status = '1' or status = '2'
```

Comment: Query time = 0.0240s on a table with 50k users. It seems to be more efficient when using WHERE rather than GROUP BY

Comment: There's a mistake in your query btw ... replace 2nd "when" with "then"

Answer (score 3):

You can group by the status and sum up the different status like this.

```
select status, 
       sum(status = 1) as status1_count,
       sum(status = 2) as status2_count,
       sum(status = 3) as status3_count
from users
group by status
```

which is MySQL syntax. General SQL ANSI syntax would be

```
select status, 
       sum(case when status = 1 then 1 end) as status1_count,
       sum(case when status = 2 then 1 end) as status2_count,
       sum(case when status = 3 then 1 end) as status3_count
from users
group by status
```

Comment: That was fast, and it works! Thanks

Comment: Query1 time = 0.0395s on a table with 50k users; Query2 time = 0.0250s on 2nd query on a table with 50k users

Comment: these queries return 2 unnecessary columns for each status

Comment: when status = '0' they will return row '0', some_count, 0, 0; when status = '1' they will return row '1', 0, some_count, 0